# RxJava 1.0: Block till nested subscriber is done

Tags: rx-java

I have the following flow. I want to block till I am done with all the Google calls in the nested subscriber. If I put *toBlocking*, code does not run. Basically, I want to access the cache once I am done with all the calls to Google.

```
            cartesian
            .doOnCompleted(() -> { System.out.println(" DOC#1 # ELEMENTS IN CACHE " + cache.size()); })
            .filter((CartesianProduct cp) -> !cache.containsKey(cp.fromTo))
            .groupBy((cp) -> cp.from)
            .subscribe((group) -> {
                GeoLocation from = (GeoLocation) ((GroupedObservable)group).getKey();
                //Google Maps API allows max 25 Destinations per call
                ((GroupedObservable)group).window(25)
                .doOnCompleted(() -> { System.out.println(" DOC#2 # ELEMENTS IN CACHE " + cache.size()); })
                .subscribe((window) -> {
                    ((rx.subjects.UnicastSubject)window).asObservable().toList()
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.from(httpExecutor))
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> { System.out.println(" DOC#3 # ELEMENTS IN CACHE " + cache.size()); })
                    .subscribe( (list) -> {
                        //Call Google Maps API here
                        List<CartesianProduct> toList = (List<CartesianProduct>) list;
                        List<GeoLocation> targets = new ArrayList();
                        for (CartesianProduct cP : toList) {
                            targets.add(cP.to);
                        }
                        GoogleMapsClientWrapper.getDistanceAndDurationForDirection(from, targets, cache);
                    });                 
                });
            });         

            System.out.println(" # ELEMENTS IN CACHE " + cache.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nesting it into individual `subscribe`, use `flatMap`

```
cartesian
.doOnCompleted(() -> { System.out.println(" DOC#1 # ELEMENTS IN CACHE " + cache.size()); })
.filter((CartesianProduct cp) -> !cache.containsKey(cp.fromTo))
.groupBy((cp) -> cp.from)
.flatMap((group) -> {
    GeoLocation from = (GeoLocation) ((GroupedObservable)group).getKey();
    //Google Maps API allows max 25 Destinations per call
    return ((GroupedObservable)group).window(25)
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> { System.out.println(" DOC#2 # ELEMENTS IN CACHE " + cache.size()); });
})
.flatMap((window) -> {
    return ((rx.subjects.UnicastSubject)window).asObservable().toList()
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.from(httpExecutor))
                    .doOnCompleted(() -> { System.out.println(" DOC#3 # ELEMENTS IN CACHE " + cache.size()); });
})
.flatMap( (list) -> {
    List<CartesianProduct> toList = (List<CartesianProduct>) list;
    List<GeoLocation> targets = new ArrayList();
    for (CartesianProduct cP : toList) {
            targets.add(cP.to);
    }
    return GoogleMapsClientWrapper.getDistanceAndDurationForDirection(from, targets, cache);
})
.subscribe(s -> {
    System.out.println("Everything is done");
});
```